# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'account' | El módulo sí que está añadido en settings como una app más

Tags: python, django

Devuelve el siguiente error. Pero el módulo ya está añadido como una app más 'account'.

¿Qué puede estar sucediendo?

Gracias.

Error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Settings: (se ve que account ya está añadido)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Error completo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

applications > account > apps.py

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Lo que agregas en `settings` `INSTALLED_APPS` para la app `account` es `account.apps.AccountConfig`.

Comment: Añado el app.py

Comment: Ahora se ve bien. La verdad es que no se qué sucedía. Gracias de todos modos.